# Conditions for Fubini's theorem in simple terms

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Could someone explain the conditions required to satisfy Fubini's theorem in layman's terms, without going into measure theory? I'm a high school student trying to gain a simple understanding of when Fubini's theorem doesn't apply, but everything I've found online is in terms of measure spaces. Would it be possible to explain the conditions in terms of continuity and boundedness over the region of integration?

Comment: I assume you are primarily interested in the case of euclidean spaces, which simplifies matters a bit. It is not possible to explain the conditions in terms of continuity and boundedness of a region, because the theorem is both deeper and vastly more general than that. The conditions are actually extremely simple, however: the theorem holds whenever the integrals involved make sense. Something that may be what you're looking for is: The conditions of Fubini's theorem are satisfied for a continuous function on a compact set. While that is a sufficient criterion, it is far from necessary.

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks for your reply. I've seen it stated in various places that the condition for Fubini's theorem is that the double integral of the absolute value of the function must be finite. How does this relate to continuity? What if you had a discontinuous function where the integral of the absolute value is finite (if this is even possible)? Would Fubini's theorem still hold?

Comment: That is indeed the condition and, from a measure-theoretic viewpoint, this is required for the "integral to make sense", which is what I was alluding to. This does not directly "relate" to continuity, it's much more general. It is possible to have a discontinuous integrable function and Fubini's theorem does still hold for those; in fact, you can easily find such functions which are discontinuous everywhere. So continuity is in no way necessary, but it is sufficient as long as you are integrating over a compact set.

Comment: Ah okay that makes a lot more sense. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Thorgott Is the condition that the integral of the absolute value is finite known as the Lebesgue integrability condition? Or is that something different?

Comment: It's known as being Lebesgue-integrable. Lebesgue's integrability condition is a different thing (it is a characterization of Riemann-integrability).

Comment: @Thorgott Ok thanks! So, in summary, Fubini's theorem can be applied to Lebesgue-integrable functions (integral of the absolute value is finite and the function is measurable). And just to clarify, when you say "It is possible to have a discontinuous integrable function and Fubini's theorem does still hold", do you mean Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Yes, indeed.$\ \ $

Comment: @Thorgott And would I be right in saying that the same conditions mentioned previously also apply to the stronger form of Fubini's theorem for more general regions whose shapes are determined by functions - e.g. a < x < b and g1(x) < y < g2(x)?

Comment: Yes, granted that these regions are sufficiently nice (meaning measurable).

Comment: Okay thanks so much for all your help! It's really cleared a lot of my confusion.

Comment: @Thorgott Hi sorry to bother you again but I had a question I was hoping you might be able to help me with. I had asked this earlier on Maths Stack Exchange but didn't receive any answers. There are some functions that are improperly Riemann integrable but not Lebesgue integrable (e.g. sinx/x). Since Lebesgue integrability is the criterion for Fubini's theorem to apply, I was wondering how we would proceed in these cases? Thanks so much

Comment: @Thorgott just to slightly clarify my question - I'm referring to conditionally convergent improper Riemann integrals, which are beyond Lebesgue integration.

Comment: The best method in this case would probably be to consider the [Henstock-Kurzweil integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral), which generalizes both the Riemann and Lebesgue integral, instead, for which there are adapted versions of Fubini's theorem. The standard reference seems to be Theorem 8.13 in Swartz' book, with only the hypothesis of HK-integrability. BTW, this site doesn't like extended discussion in comments too much, especially when it's not about the original question. I recommend using the official chatroom instead; you can also ping me there.

Answer (score 0):

Another version of Fubini's theorem states that if $A$ and $B$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, not necessarily complete, and if either
$$
\int_{A}\left(\int_{B}|f(x, y)| \mathrm{d} y\right) \mathrm{d} x<\infty \quad \text { or } \quad \int_{B}\left(\int_{A}|f(x, y)| \mathrm{d} x\right) \mathrm{d} y<\infty
$$
then
$$
\int_{A \times B}|f(x, y)| \mathrm{d}(x, y)<\infty
$$
and
$$
\int_{A}\left(\int_{B} f(x, y) \mathrm{d} y\right) \mathrm{d} x=\int_{B}\left(\int_{A} f(x, y) \mathrm{d} x\right) \mathrm{d} y=\int_{A \times B} f(x, y) \mathrm{d}(x, y)
$$
In this version the condition that the measures are $\sigma$-finite is necessary.

Comment: Source: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_12/fubini.pdf

Comment: The op is a high school student and mentions clearly that op wants a simple intuitive understanding of Fubini's theorem . To make sense of what you have written, the op needs to pass an elementary course in Real Analysis  followed by an advanced one where op would learn Riemann integration and then a formal course on Measure Theory which would take him another 3 years to fully do so .